# Can I avoid multiple if-else statements in this case?

Tags: java

What is the better way to handle this piece of code

I have a method as shown below , which will accept a parameter i String and returns a int value

below code works fine .

```
public static int getLoggerLevel(String level)
 {
        int loglevel = 3;
        if (level.equals("INFO")) {
            loglevel = 3;
        }
        else if (level.equals("ERROR")) {
            loglevel = 4;
        } else if (level.equals("FATAL")) {
            loglevel = 5;
        }

        return loglevel;

}
```

I thought of putting the Key Values in Map , and retrieve that based on the String , but dont want to create an Map i guess which will consume memory

Comment: Are you *really, really, really* strapped for memory? A map with three values isn't going to take much memory...

Comment: Is the environment really *that* memory constrained that you can't use Java's basic structures? If so, is there a benefit in even using Java and not going for a language that produces more memory compact types, like C?

Comment: Any update on your progress?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming Java 7:

```
public static int getLoggerLevel(String level)
{
        switch(level){
            case "ERROR": return 4;
            case "FATAL": return 5;
            case "INFO": 
            default: return 3;
        }
}
```

On a more general note, you should probably use an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of a string for this sort of thing. It's a perfect fit. Moreover, it will also work in Java 6.

---

Here is an alternative solution using enums:

```
public enum SeverityLevel {
    ERROR, FATAL, INFO
}

 public static int getLoggerLevel(SeverityLevel level)
 {
     switch(level){
          case ERROR: return 4; 
          case FATAL: return 5; 
          case INFO: 
          default: return 3;
     }
 }
```

No quotes around them, they are enum values, this approach also mitigates bugs caused by typing errors. The big bonus is conceptual though, `getLoggerLevel` now accepts a `SeverityLevel` and not a string.

Comment: Java 6 compatibility is overrated, since it's end-of-lifed. ;-) (Now, if you're coding for Android, that's a different story.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Completely Right. I think that Java 6 compatibility is not the stronger argument towards using an ENUM (rather than strings) here. Enums are designed for these sort of things. Conceptually logger levels aren't strings, they're logger levels :) (Also, what Brian said)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young You don't work in the real world, do you? ;) There are companies out there that still use *1.5* (Or lower ::cringe:: )

Comment: @BrianRoach I realise that (at work, we're only just now completing our switch to Java 7). But I take the same stance as Guava, which is "we are not going to support people using 1.5 or lower". ;-) (Okay, Guava actually does have a special 1.5-compatible branch. But it's still a second-class citizen. :-P)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum liked your answer . good one , thank you .

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Agree re enum being better for this, of course.

Comment: It's worth noting that switch statements for strings and enums will throw exceptions on `null` values.

Comment: Chris, thanks.  @PreethiJain If you have any more questions regarding this answer let me know. If you feel that this solved your issue please consider accepting this answer. Mike, +1 good point.

Comment: Just a nit but if efficiency is an issue I think you can remove the case "INFO": statement

Comment: @MikeC That's a nice point however I like letting my jits do that sort of optimizing for me. The fact 'INFO' is there (or INFO in the enum version) indicates that it is a state of affairs the method expects. If we drop the "INFO line" we're no longer explicitly saying that it's an expected possible value in our code. It's just a matter of coding style.

Comment: I don't know if it apply to java but at least in c# using the default that way is a bad practice. By "mitigating bug caused by typing error" you risk to create bug elsewhere which may be harder to find.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini What do you mean? (Also take note C# switch works differently from Java catch, for example C# has no fallthrough). Also Java enums work completely differently from C# enums (although in that case it's pretty similar)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum if I pass to the switch a wrong value it will be threated as it is right but probably the wrong value shouldn't have been passed in the first place, by throwing an exception or using an assertion in the default the developer is able to find instantly that there is something that isn't working how it should. by correcting the value using the default the program work correctly in the switch but may crash elsewhere and the developer may not remember/know about the default behavior and can't understand why a new enum/value e.g. WARNING become INFO at runtime

Comment: Right, an ENUM _does_ mitigate that because if you access an ENUM value with a spelling mistake for example you get a compile time error. I agree that the default is risky and I would not do that. In my code the level would probably be a method on the ENUM (Java unlike C# lets you do that, one of the few things going for Java in that battle). However, if that's what you meant (the permissive default) I absolutely agree, in my code that would have been a 'throw'. Then again I also understand developers that don't want to bother with logger exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

A map would work and would hardly consume any memory, especially if scoped appropriately so that it was just created once.

Answer (score 0):

Use Switch- case simple to read and understand.

```
public static int getLoggerLevel(String level)
{
    switch(level){
        case "ERROR": return 4;
        case "FATAL": return 5;
        case "INFO": 
        default: return 3;
    }
}
```

Also, in your code , you can avoid 1st if block.
And once you found correct match.. use return there which will avoid checking further code.
 which will make your code as below

```
public static int getLoggerLevel(String level)
{
    int loglevel = 3;
    if (level.equals("ERROR")) {
        return 4;
    } else if (level.equals("FATAL")) {
        return 5;
    }
    return loglevel;
```

}

Comment: Not me, but probably because this answer was posted later and provided no insight over the already existing ones.